# Custom queryset returning multiple model instances to serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to build my own API. I've built multiple methods without any problems but I stumbled upon a situation where I can't find a solution.

I have a GET method which internally creates a queryset which gets multiple instances from the same model that are related with the current user. This is how my view looks like:

```
class getTheList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GetTheThingListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        the_thing = TheThing.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return the_thing.get_other_things(user)
```

As it can be seen, I have overriden `get_queryset()`. Now [according to the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects), I should pass the queryset and `many=True` as parameters for the serializer. However, I have no way to access this custom queryset (self.get_queryset() won't work obviously). And if I do not pass the `many=True` parameter, the serializer will only receive one object and not multiple.

I have been successful with querysets when defined at the top of the class, but not when `get_queryset()` is overriden. How should I proceed?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but the above would be more efficient if you made a Manager method `get_related_things` that takes a thing pk and returns a queryset, rather than having to first fetch the object, then the related objects

Comment: That's an indeed unwanted but awesome suggestion that I'll be applying from now on. I should continue reading (Django in general) to not miss these things. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class `ListAPIView` internally instantiates the serializer with `many=true`, as you can [see in the source.](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L34)

If your `get_queryset()` method actually return a queryset, you should be fine.

Only when you instantiate the serializer directly, then you have to pass `many=true`

Comment: I can see that you are right so definitely this is not the real issue behind my problem. However this answers my question and helps me, thank you!